# apt-get install build-essentials fails on Ubuntu 11.10 on aws ami-baba68d3

Tags: ubuntu, installation, apt

I was trying to install and configure Xabbix on an ubuntu server.  Following their instructions on the wiki the first step fails:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

I get the following error message:

```
Err http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-updates/main linux-libc-dev amd64 3.0.0-16.28
404  Not Found [IP: 10.252.111.96 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-security/main linux-libc-dev amd64 3.0.0-16.28
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.166 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-libc-dev_3.0.0-16.28_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.166 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing
```

I tried the suggesting of --fix-missing.  No luck there.

Comment: I just found the solution.  apt-get update

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I ran:
    apt-get update

Then I was able to run the build-essential installation.

Answer (score 2):

I was not able to install build-essential even after apt-get update. Actually apt-get also failed. This was (in my case) because Ubuntu moves the older version packages (after its support cycle ends) to different URLs. Thus, it will not be accessible to the package manager. The proper solution is to upgrade. But most of the time it is a difficult option, thus we can change the url inside /etc/apt/sources.list 
from ..**in.archive**.ubuntu.com/.. to  ..**old-releases**.ubuntu.com/..

Thanks, please refer to the below for the complete explanation
https://smyl.es/how-to-fix-ubuntudebian-apt-get-404-not-found-package-repository-errors-saucy-raring-quantal-oneiric-natty/